# October CMS - API Generator - how to create and update data in database

Tags: ajax, api, octobercms

I try to send data to the database using AJAX and plugin in October CMS called "API Generator".
I can't find in its documentation or in Google anything that will help me.

The code I have is this:

```
$data = [{'room_id': {{room.id}}, 'amount': amount, 'arrival': '2018-04-01', 'departure': '2018-04-03,', 'reservation_type': 'owner'}]

$.ajax({
  url: '/api/v1/booking/create',
  data: $data,
  type: "post"
})
.done(function() {
  console.log('Success')
})
.fail(function() {
  console.warn('Something went wrong');
});
```

I don't get any error, in fact, I get 'Success' message in console, but data is not added to the database.

What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: I cant realized what are you doing, help me out

Comment: I've created API for my bookings with this "API Generator" plugin, and I try to send data of new booking to API to add it to the database.
$data is a temporary static object to add to database.

Comment: It cannot find a solution, you must send your serverside code where you connect to your database

Comment: Did you read this? https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/controllers-ajax#ajax-handlers

Comment: Yes, I did.
I can't do it that way, because I'm not using forms or buttons.
That's why I'm using ["API Generator" plugin](https://octobercms.com/plugin/ahmadfatoni-apigenerator).
I found in this plugin code what URL should be to delete element and it works, but I can't figure out how to add and edit elements

Comment: Instead of using third party plugin, I would suggest you to create your own plugin for APIs and inside `routes.php` after you create this file, u can create your own apis and responses from php code. I follow this way.  I feel I dont have that much control when I use third party plugins. You can do something like this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40610006/create-api-web-service-in-octobercms. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't have so much time for this project to create own API, but anyway thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are doing it little wrong **[** You are firing Ajax request at `wrong end-point` **]** that Api Plugin is based on https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers `Resource Controller`

> So, To create an item you need to fire only `POST` request to `Created Api-End Point`. You don't need to send `Array` just send simple plain `Object`

**Refactored your code ( this should work ):**

```
// Plaing object no array
$data = {'room_id': {{room.id}}, 'amount': amount, 'arrival': '2018-04-01',
       'departure': '2018-04-03,', 'reservation_type': 'owner'};

$.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/booking', // <- just your Api-End [no create/store]
    data: $data,
    type: "post" // <- this post request indicates that you want to create/insert
})
.done(function(response) {
    // this will always fire when status code is 200
    console.log('Success', response); 
})
.fail(function() {
    // when status code is not 200 this will execute
    console.warn('Something went wrong');
});
```

> **Why you get `success` although its not Creating Record ?**

Because according to `Resource Controller` there is no method `create` in `api generator controller` so `October CMS` is treating `/api/v1/booking/create` [POST] request as `404 page not found` and its serving [200] status code with `404 page not found` as `ajax response`.

> And 404 page is having 200 status code so it fall in to `success` category and `Ajax thinks it's a successful request` and prints `success` message in console.

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: Thanks, for answer, it really helps :)
But there was another problem in plugin itself, which causing 505 error.
There was lack of Validator class file import in template of API controller.

Comment: yes, i also see that some of things are not working as expected, hope author will correct them soon :)