# OctoberCMS: set multiple models in one API endpoint

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend

I build backend with OctobderCMS for mobile app and need to have API for the app,  i have around 15 models and want to have 2 API endpoint for these models,
One endpoint for 2-3 models and the other enpoint for the rest of the models.

Can i make this happen?

Comment: However, this has been answers and solved below. Check my link with question and answer what I had done for the same. Its step by step answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40625088/6829420 . Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes definitely, you can make APIs using all models of your OctoberCMS.

You have to make `routes.php` file in your **Plugin** directory where your all models belong. And in `routes.php` file you have to maintain your results with queries.

**Example of `routes.php` file is below:**

```
<?php

//Here you have to define your route.
Route::get('api/v1/your_route', function () {
    $result = [];    //define a variable as array

    $wartaProfiles= \WartaProfil::where('id','1')->get();;
    $jadwalKeb = \JadwalKeb::all();

    $result['wartaProfiles'] = $wartaProfiles;
    $result['jadwalKeb'] = $jadwalKeb;
    return $result;
});
```

I have two models **Recipe** and **Category** so I have mixed both models results in **$result** and returning it.
Now you can define your models and do whatever results you want.

For more information about retrieving results from models, visit this [Retrieving multiple models](https://octobercms.com/docs/database/model#retrieving-multiple-models).

That's all form my side. Hope this will help you.

Comment if you have any doubts.

Comment: I know `routes.php` for API but i dont how to define function for multiple model
I find out this `Response::Json($model)` so how to define multiple model..

Comment: Can you show your some of models, so i can give you example.

Comment: @IsralBustami I have updated my answer with an example. Check it

Comment: i want these models in one API

`WartaProfil::where('id','1')->get();
JadwalKeb::get();`

Comment: I have updated my answer. Don't forget to define a path for your models like `\Horizonstack\Blwapp\Models\Category` mine model path.

Comment: So we do not need to define `$result` as `Response::JSON($result)` isnt it?

Comment: The JSON method will automatically set the Content-Type header to application/json, as well as convert the given array into JSON using the json_encode PHP function. And You have all your results in **$result** so you have to define $result.

Comment: So i can define as many models as i need with the method you gave or there is limitation for number of models..

Comment: No, you can add multiple models to get your desired result. No limitation :)